# Problema con LIMIT en Rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Quuiero introducir una variable en una consulta, y esta me genera un error, alguien me puede explicar lo que pasa?

Aqui el código:

```
    #Ordenamos el arreglo menor, de menor a mayor
    @menor=@menor.sort
    #Seleccionamos el menor del arreglo menor
    @m=@menor.take(1)
    #Seleccionamos las muestras de cada periodo, la cantidad de muestras viene dada por el valor de la variable @m
    Item.where("periodo=1 AND año='2017'").limit("#{@m}")
    @prueba=[]
    @consultaPrueba.each do |consulta|
        @prueba.push(consulta.ventClient)
    end
```

Al ejecutar la consulta me genera el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te dice que valor de la variable `@m` no es un número (`limit` necesita un número como parámetro), es `[[3]]`; obtienes el valor como consecuencia de utilizar `take` (que te devuelve un arreglo) e interpolar su valor (que lo convierte a *String*).

Considera los siguientes ejemplos:

```
@m = [2, 1, 3]
#=> [2, 1, 3]

@m.take(1)
#=> [2]

"#{@m.take(1)}"
#=> "[2]"
```

Si quieres tomar el número más pequeño de un arreglo puedes utilizar `min`:

```
@m.min
#=> 1
```

Tu código se vería así:

```
Item.where("periodo=1 AND año='2017'").limit(@m.min)
```

Comment: Gracias funcionó perfectamente!